# Unable to increment custom field in Meteor.users collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am unable to increment custom field in Meteor.users collection. The client updates for a second but then the server rejects the change. The code does work on mongo console though:

```
Template.profile.events({
    'click .follow': function(e) {    
        var followed = this.userProfile._id;
        var follower = Meteor.user()._id;
        Meteor.call('updateFollowers',followed,follower);
    } 
});

Meteor.methods({
    updateFollowers: function(followed,follower) 
    {
        alert(followed);
        var affected = Meteor.users.update({ _id: followed } ,{ $inc: {followersCount: 1}});
        alert(affected);
    }
});
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Do you use `alert()` on the server? If so, that's why the server rejects the change: The method throws an exception because `alert` isn't defined. You should normally see a big bright exception (`ReferenceError`) in the console in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it like two seconds after posting! Simply move the code to a server side folder, the collections folder in my case.

Comment: I have no idea why someone down voted you. You should maybe clear up your explanation in your answer a little bit and then accept your own answer! This may help someone in the future. Good job!

Comment: Hey man thanks. I can accept my answer in 20 hours so I'll do that.